# Javascript TIC TAC TOE - AI not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am building a tic tac toe game where one can play an AI. In the `$scope.move function()` there is a while loop that grabs a random cell and makes it the value of the AI. Somehow this is not working. Here's the codepen link http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/ojJrRp

```
    var app = angular.module("ticTacToe", []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  var cell = $(".square");
  $scope.player = "";
   $scope.AI = "";
  var cross = "×";
  var circle = "◯";


  /*** Choose a shape ***/
  $scope.choosePlayer = function(e) {
  $scope.player = $(e.currentTarget).text();
        $('.choose').css('top', '-2000px');
        $('#wrapper').css('top', '-600px');
        $('#wrapper').css('opacity', '1');
    if($scope.player === "×"){
    $scope.AI = "◯";
    }else if($scope.player === "◯"){
    $scope.AI = "×";
  }
}

  /*** Shape Cells ***/
  $scope.cells = [ { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, 
     { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' } ,
    { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }  
  ];

  /*** Make a move ***/
  $scope.move = function(cell){
    cell.value = $scope.player;
    var round = 0;
    /*** AI makes a move ***/
    while(round < 1){
      var randomCell = $scope.cells[Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1)];
      if(randomCell.value === "" ){
      randomCell.value = $scope.AI;
      round = 1;
      }else{
        round = 0;
      } 
    }

  };


});
```

Comment: var randomCell = $scope.cells[Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1)];

Don't think you want +1 in this one.  You're going from 1 to 9 for a 0-indexed array.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I have changed your code a bit and added comments where I saw the problem

```
var app = angular.module("ticTacToe", []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  var cell = $(".square");
  $scope.player = "";
  $scope.AI = "";
  // changed special chars to X and O as the if statement failed.
  var cross = "X";
  var circle = "O";


  /*** Choose a shape ***/
  $scope.choosePlayer = function(e) {
  $scope.player = $(e.currentTarget).text();
        $('.choose').css('top', '-2000px');
        $('#wrapper').css('top', '-600px');
        $('#wrapper').css('opacity', '1');
    //these if statements failed before (AI was always empty)
    if($scope.player === cross){
    $scope.AI = circle;
    }else if($scope.player === circle){
    $scope.AI = cross;
  }
}

  /*** Shape Cells ***/
  $scope.cells = [ { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, 
     { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' } ,
    { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }  
  ];
  // made a ref to scope cells
  $scope.emptyCells = $scope.cells;

  /*** Make a move ***/
  $scope.move = function(cell){
    cell.value = $scope.player;
    var round = 0;
    /*** AI makes a move ***/
    while(round < 1){
     // filtered to get only available cells (for performance)
      $scope.emptyCells = $scope.cells.filter(function(cell){
        return cell.value === '';
      });
      // got random cell according to empty cells
      var randomCell =  $scope.emptyCells[Math.floor((Math.random()*($scope.emptyCells.length-1))+1)];
      if(randomCell.value === "" ){
      randomCell.value = $scope.AI;
      round = 1;
      }else{
        round = 0;
      } 
    }

  };


});
```

also needed to change in HTML:

```
<button ng-click="choosePlayer($event)" class="btn btn-red" id="choose-cross">X</button>
<button ng-click="choosePlayer($event)" class="btn btn-green" id="choose-circle">O</button>
```

Comment: In other words, your X's and O's in your HTML didn't match what you were checking in your player function.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong unicode character for crosses based on your HTML. Change it to ✖ and it will work.

Avoid the use of "magic values". Simply assign `cross` and `circle` to the correct values once, and then refer to cross and circle everywhere else in your code. This will help to prevent future errors of this kind since the values will have *one* point of reference and can be easily changed rather than digging through your code and changing all the incorrect string literals.

Ideally, the best practice would be have everything based on one central point of reference. So either your HTML should refer to the variables in your JS or your JS should refer to the text node in your HTML. This is a software development principle known as DRY or Dont Repeat Yourself, and basically it means that the only repetitions in your code should be references to other code. A string literal should not be repeated. Instead repeat a *reference* to that string literal.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpbaLz

Updated JS:

```
var app = angular.module("ticTacToe", []);
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  var cell = $(".square");
  $scope.player = "";
   $scope.AI = "";
  // *** fixed unicode char 
  var cross = "✖";
  var circle = "◯";

  /*** Choose a shape ***/
  $scope.choosePlayer = function(e) {
  $scope.player = $(e.currentTarget).text();
        $('.choose').css('top', '-2000px');
        $('#wrapper').css('top', '-600px');
        $('#wrapper').css('opacity', '1');
    // *** use correct unicode chars above 
    if($scope.player === cross){
      $scope.AI = circle;
    }else if($scope.player === circle){
      $scope.AI = cross;
    }
  }

  /*** Shape Cells ***/
  $scope.cells = [ { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, 
     { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' } ,
    { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }  
  ];

  /*** Make a move ***/
  $scope.move = function(cell){
    cell.value = $scope.player;
    var round = 0;
    /*** AI makes a move ***/
    while(round < 1){
      // *** random select fix
      var randomCell = $scope.cells[Math.floor((Math.random()*9))];
      if(randomCell.value === "" ){
        randomCell.value = $scope.AI;
        round = 1;
      }else{
        round = 0;
      } 
    }
  };


});
```

Comment: your code will not allow him to finish the game so easily (infinite loop, or almost)

Comment: @Saar I don't care if his game finishes. This answer solves the problem in the question which is the AI not selecting a move and that's all that matters.

Comment: That seems to solve the problem using the special characters. I thought I had the right unicode.